# A doubt regarding standard limit $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}$

Tags: calculus, limits

In the standard limit:
$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}$$
This limit is obviously eligible for L'Hôpital's rule as it is of form $\frac{0}{0}$. Thus when we differentiate the numerator and the denominator with respect to $x$, we get:
$$\lim_{x \to a} nx^{n-1} = na^{n-1}$$
So, my doubt was that is there any use of the constants $a^n$ and $a$ in the function whose limit at $a$ had to be found? Or can we just have any other constants too?

Comment: " This limit is obviously eligible for l'Hopital as it is of form $\frac 00$ "

Comment: But to apply the Hospital you need to be able to differentiate $x^n$, and that requires knowing the limit you seek.

Comment: Ignoring the circularity for a moment, you only apply L'Hopital once you know the numerator and denominator are zero, which is only the case when $x=a$, and then $a$ is fixed in the analysis as the limit of $x$.  If there was another constant $b$, then you would have $\lim_{x_\to b}.

Comment: @WADon Oh..yeah thank you:) I think I ignored that fact. Sorry for posting such a silly question